# When conn switch data, if there is no data for transmitting, what will happen?

Tags: go

When I read the [opensource code:](https://github.com/LiamHaworth/go-tproxy/blob/ef7efd7f24ed7e9bf8f479c890c81ce7db27000e/example/tproxy_example.go#L159)

there have this code below:

```
    streamConn := func(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader) {
        io.Copy(dst, src)
        streamWait.Done()
    }
    go streamConn(remoteConn, conn)
    go streamConn(conn, remoteConn)
```

you see there use two `go streamConn()` to switch the data between two `conn`.
and I want to know if the `remoteConn` do not have data to transmit, there copy what? copy `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually network sockets operate in *blocking* mode – if there's no more data to be received, then the "receive" operation will just **sit there and wait** until there is some. That's why there are two goroutines, one in each direction – so that one could keep copying data while the other is still waiting for data (blocked on read).

For a similar but more direct example, you'll find a direct call to `remoteConn.Read(data)` a bit higher up in the same file. When called, Read() won't return until it gets *some* data – or until it reaches the timeout that was set using SetReadDeadline() immediately above (in which case it'll return a Timeout error through `err`).

Comment: if `"receive" operation will just sit there and wait until there is some` do not receive data, the handleTCP will not close, right?